# C# Excel 2016 interop new Charts

Tags: c#, excel, charts, interop

We need to create new Excel 2016 graph in C# by interop.

in vba we can use this :
All of my vba code is generate by recording macro :

```
Sub Macro3()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(410, xlTreemap).Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graphique 9").Activate
End Sub
```

For old chart, in C# we use this :

```
var shapes = _ActiveSheet.Shapes;
Shape shape = ((dynamic)shapes).AddChart2(-1, type); // type = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered
```

In XlChartType we don't have any xlTreemap.

How can i do that ?

ps : we currently use "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" version 15

Regards,

Tristan

Comment: In your VBA code, where **else** do you see `xlTreemap`?  I think that was likely a pre-defined variable, assigned to a different value.  You just need to pull that into the C# code as well at some point.

Comment: I agree, but in XlChartType enums, we haven't any xlTreemap value

Comment: It's *not an XlChartType* - it's a variable, _you_ defined, most likely.  `Ctrl+F` all of the VBA code, and find *all* instances of `xlTreemap`

Comment: Wrong interop version, 15 matches Office 2013 and it certainly doesn't have an xlTreemap.  Your code would fail if the user had an older Excel version.  The object model has been stable for a very long time but they could not keep this up forever.  The Shapes object in particular has been changing in recent versions.  Progress.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant,
What version of Interop we can use ?
I searched it via nuget, and not found any other

Comment: gravity : I edit my question :
All of my vba code is generate by recording macro.
I haven't other vba code in my workbook